# How to compile JSX with Babel into JavaScript

Tags: node.js, browserify, babeljs, reactjs

I'm trying to compile the very simplest React tutorial using browserify. I've run:

```
sudo npm install browserify
```

Then as stated here http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#browserify

```
sudo npm install --save-dev babelify
```

Then I have my file `js/script.jsx`

```
var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage name="John" />, mountNode);
```

And I'm running from the folder

```
browserify js/script.jsx -t babelify --outfile bundle.js
```

But then this happens:

```
djave at djaves-iMac-3 in /Volumes/djave/react
$ browserify js/script.jsx -t babelify --outfile bundle.js
SyntaxError: /Volumes/djave/react/js/script.jsx: Unexpected token (4:11)
  2 | var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
  3 |   render: function() {
> 4 |     return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
    |            ^
  5 |   }
  6 | });
  7 |
```

What am I doing wrong? This is literally my first step into this area so it may be I've missed a pretty major step.

*More errors* (although I suspect this won't help too much!)

```
 at Parser.pp.raise (/Volumes/djave/react/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1425:13)
 at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Volumes/djave/react/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2907:8)
 at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/Volumes/djave/react/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:754:12)
 at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/Volumes/djave/react/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:509:19)
 at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/Volumes/djave/react/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:489:19)
 at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/Volumes/djave/react/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:420:19)
```

Comment: Did you download any babel presets? Check out the docs here https://github.com/babel/babelify

Comment: ahh – just in the process of doing that since your comment – it looks like http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/ is what I'm after – thanks

Answer (score 3):

All fixed, thanks to @azium.

First get the React preset: http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/

```
npm install babel-preset-react
```

Next, create a file called .babelrc in the root of your project, and put in it the following:

```
{
  "presets": ["react"]
}
```

Then do the

```
browserify js/script.jsx -t babelify --outfile bundle.js
```

That compiles everything, and as an extra to make sure that `react` and `react-dom` are included ([as shown here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html)) you can run the following:

```
sudo npm install --save react react-dom
```

Comment: why you need use browserify  , with gulp installed globally is not enough?  I run just "gulp" from terminal, and then i get jsx files compiled , configuring just .babelrc and gulpfile.js